# trouble building Docker image on Windows: /systemlibs.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 126

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, mwaa

I'm looking to build a Docker image on Windows following the following steps:
git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner.git
cd aws-mwaa-local-runner

This is where I get stuck. Running this command, I get an error:
set PWD=%cd%&& docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose-local.yml up

[image]

Has anyone come across this error?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around: in wsl, do dos2unix: `script/filename.sh` on all `*.sh` files.

- Then run set :

```
PWD=%cd%&& docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose-local.yml up
```

This resolved the `exit 126 error`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes from the first line of the /systemlibs.h file.

If you look in details in the folders that you clone from [your git repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner.git),
you will find the script in

`aws-mwaa-local-runner/docker/script/systemlibs.h`

The first line starts with **#!/bin/sh**, but I think the encoding of the file adds a ***^M*** at the end of the line, that you can't see.

***Try to delete the first line of this file and see.***

If you look in details at the error you have, the penultimate line gives you an error that matches with what I said : the files /systemlibs.h (actually the one  I told you but it is moved during the init of the docker container) tries to load /bin/sh^M, wich is the first line of the file.

If you need more details, take a look at this [article](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/shell-script-error-bad-interpreter-no-such-file/).

Comment: hi, thank you for your suggestions. I removed #!/bin/sh and re-ran
set PWD=%cd%&& docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose-local.yml up

now I'm getting this error:

 => ERROR [10/21] RUN chmod u+x /systemlibs.sh && /systemlibs.sh                                                                       0.7s
------
 > [10/21] RUN chmod u+x /systemlibs.sh && /systemlibs.sh:
#0 0.617 /systemlibs.sh: line 1: $'\r': command not found
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c chmod u+x /systemlibs.sh && /systemlibs.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

Comment: it's still because of the encoding of the *End of line* character. Your file is saved as **CRLF** end of line character, you have to save it as **LF**. (You can do it in the right bottom in VSCode for example)